# How to print a string in assembly intel x86 without changing the data

Tags: assembly, intel, cpu-architecture

I have this piece:

```
.global main

.data
helloworld: .ascii "Hello world\n"
helloworldend:
goodluck: .asciz "Good Luck!\n"
goodluckend:

.text
main:
    # printf(helloworld)
    movq $1, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $helloworld, %rsi
    movq $helloworldend-helloworld, %rdx
    syscall

    # printf(goodluck)
    movq $1, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $goodluck, %rsi
    movq $goodluckend-goodluck, %rdx
    syscall

    xorq %rax, %rax
    ret
```

And I have to somehow make it also print "Hello Luck" without changing the data section.
What I did is add a new data section inside the main:

```
...
main:
   
.section .data
msg: .ascii "Hello Luck\n"
msgend:

.section .text
start:
    movq $1, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $msg, %rsi
    movq $msgend-msg, %rdx
    syscall
...
```

And obviously that works but I'm not sure that that was the idea.. Is there a different way of printing it without adding a new data section and without changing the existing one?

Comment: You can of course change the string from code at runtime.

Comment: Does changing the string with a store count as changing the data section? Can you print part of the string and then make the rest at runtime and print that? It's unclear under what rules we are playing.

Comment: @MargaretBloom can't change the data at all

Comment: @Jester how? I'm new to this was using C , C++ and python until now

Comment: If you can't really change the data (either at runtime) then you have to print `Good ` and then make `day\n` on the stack and print that. Or make the whole string altogether.

Comment: @MargaretBloom so take the first part of "Good luck"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel syscall `sys_write` expects `RDX`=number of bytes and `RSI`=pointer to the string, which doesn't have to be null-terminated, so just change those two registers:

```
main:
    # printf("Hello ")
    movq $1, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $helloworld, %rsi    ; Pointer to "Hello World\n"
    movq $6, %rdx             ; Size of "Hello "
    syscall

    # printf("Luck")
    movq $1, %rax
    movq $goodluck + 5, %rsi  ; Pointer to "Luck!\n"
    movq $4, %rdx             ; Size of "Luck"
    syscall

    # printf("\n")
    movq $1, %rax
    movq $goodluck + 10, %rsi ; Pointer to "\n"
    movq $1, %rdx             ; Size of "\n"
    syscall

    xorq %rax, %rax
    ret
```

Comment: The *goodluck* message had an exclamation mark that was not requested in the desired output. I corrected it with a 3rd syscall.